# Safari analog of chrome.tabs.update or loadURI

Tags: safari-extension

I need analog of Chrome `chrome.tabs.update` or Firefox `loadURI` in Safari.
I've tried `safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url = newURL` but it doesn't work with bookmarklets urls like `javascript:...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, it doesn't work. You're going to have to pass a message to an injected script in a web page to open the bookmarklet. For example:

in the global page's script:

```
  var activeTab = safari.application.activeBrowerWindow.activeTab;
  var url = "javascript:alert('hello sucker')";
  activeTab.page.dispatchMessage("pleaseLoadThisUrl", url);
```

in the injected script:

```
  safari.self.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);

  function handleMessage(e) {
      if (e.name == "pleaseLoadThisUrl") {
          window.location = e.message;
      }
  }
```

That will work.